# Access to localhost from docker container

Tags: docker, casperjs

I want to access to a local webserver that is outside the docker container.

I have a testsuite (casperjs) inside a docker container that open a browser to localhost:8002/etc, but "localhost" here refers to my local machine, not something inside the docker container. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the IP of the bridge to get to the host. Docker usually is deployed the other way around though. You'd have a service inside a container beint used from outside it... (thus casperJS inside the container being hit from the host)

Or you could have the original webserver in a container and `--link` it into the casper container and utilize the host name of the webserver container:

```
docker run -p 80 --name app {your image} start
docker run --link app:app {your casperjs} start
```

and utilize the hostname "app" for accessing the webserver.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it is usually the other way around, but my needs precisely ask to do the opposite, so thanks a lot to have answer the question to the point.